# Renaming field of shapefile in SAGA

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, saga

I want to rename a field of a shapefile in SAGA. I tried:

```
saga_cmd table_tools 23 -TABLE %dgm_snap_berg% -FIELD ID_1 -NAME Berg_ID
```

`%dgm_snap_berg%` - path to the shapefile
`ID_1` - field supposed to be renamed
`Berg_ID` - the new name I want to give

The code runs, but the field is not renamed. What am I doing wrong? This is what SAGA gives out:

```
Parameters

Table: DGM_Punkte_snapped_Berg
Field: <not set>
Output: <not set>
Name: Berg_ID
```

Also, I am sure the field `ID_1` exists:

[image]

Comment: The "ID" column is a *phantom* column in ArcGIS tools. If you attempt to add an "ID" column to the dBase-III component of a shapefile, it will be dynamically renamed to "ID_1".  I haven't tried adding an explicit "ID_1" column, but I expect it would be dynamically renamed to "ID_2" (either that, or the ID would be renamed to "ID_2"). Naming shapefile fields ID_*anything* is likely to generate tool-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem... `%dgm_snap_berg%` pointed to a *.shp file. But SAGA wants to get the path to the *.dbf file which is part of the shapefile.